# How to unit test objects that depend on previous values

Tags: unit-testing

Over time I've improved my unit testing by refactoring functions so they are [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) meaning a set of inputs always produces the same output without depending on any sort of state and without causing side effects.

Occasionally I encounter scenarios for which I'm not sure how to write good unit tests such as when a function (or object) must depend on previous values. For purposes of demonstration I include this excerpt of code for an averaging filter here but really my question is quite general.

One of the reasons I created the method CAvgFilter::Clear was so that I could always insure the filter responds in a desirable way while it is being primed. While being primed CAvgFilter::Push outputs track the inputs quite closely but once the m_samples list is full, deviations to the inputs to CAvgFilter::Push are less pronounced due to the filtering.

With objects like these I usually want a way to call a method with several series of inputs while checking the outputs and ideally my unit test has as few dependencies on data ordering as possible (ideally none).

When creating test vectors I often log data from the function output, verify it manually, and then use that for future tests (to insure the class doesn't break if I refactor or modify it later). Anyway, it occurred to me that I can't exactly just use any series of inputs/outputs in the middle of some range. I have to start with the filter clear (or add some functionality to otherwise initialize it for test purposes). Can anyone offer some suggestions on how this sort of thing is tackled in unit tests? Do you always start your test in the initialized state or do you offer the unit test some way to set the initial condition?

```
CAvgFilter::CAvgFilter(int length)
{
    m_maxLength = length;
}

//pass the new value and receive the moving average
long CAvgFilter::Push(long newValue)
{
    m_samples.push_back(newValue);

    if ((int) m_samples.size() > m_maxLength)
    {
        m_samples.pop_front();
    }

    long sum = 0;

    for (FILTER_CONTAINER_IT it = m_samples.begin(); it != m_samples.end(); ++it)
    {
        sum += *it;
    }

    return (sum / (long) m_samples.size()); //cast size() as long to preserve sign of the average value
}

void CAvgFilter::Clear(void)
{
    m_samples.clear();
}
```

Comment: Having hard time to understand what is the question, you always initialize the value for a unit test... usually a test have a structure of AAA (Arrange, Act, Assert). If you don't care about the values you can use library which generate randomly values...

Comment: Whats wrong with running a test in which you generate two inputs and in a single test assert against the values of a and the expected b that depends on a?

Comment: I think my confusion is that usually when my unit tests fail, I just have to check the particular input and debug why the output is incorrect. However in a class that depends on previous values, a given input/output set could be a correct result in one scenario and an incorrect result in another scenario (depending on the history leading up to that entry). I.e. I cannot simply always say that input=3, output=3. Sometimes input=3 and output =4 or input=3 and output=2. I think my main question is simply: is it normal to have this situation or does this mean my code is poorly written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your situation is (on a general level) quite common.  For example, the behaviour of state machines depends on the history of inputs.  There are many ways of dealing with this.

- You can think of the state as just another input and just another output and re-design your function accordingly.  Your function then gets the previous state as input and will return, in addition to other outputs, the new state.  Then, the function is pure again.
- As you said, you can extend the api to bring an object into a desired state.
- You can set up input histories to feed into your object as part of your test setup.  To make this more convenient, you can create helper functions for this, so many different test cases can call these functions to bring the object into a certain state.

There are, as always, pros and cons for the different approaches.

Comment: Thanks for this. Kinda always wondered the same thing myself.

Comment: Great way of breaking down the various options. It has helped me to better analyze the problem.